# Setting "Initial Catalog" in WPF Code First Entity Framework connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, entity-framework, code-first

I'm working on a small application that I need to tie to an already existing database.

However, when I supply a connection string for entity framework to use in the App.Config file, it completely ignores the "Initial Catalog" section and creates a new database on the server. How can I make it use the already existing database?

My connection string is:

```
Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=adminMain;Integrated Security=true; MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

Answer (score 1):

After churning through page after page, and wasting the entirety of my work-day, as well as my entire evening, I finally stumbled across the solution.

By updating my context class from:

```
public class ProductContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

to:

```
public class ProductContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public ProductContext() 
        : base("adminMain")
    {

    }
}
```

It now connects to the correct database.

Answer (score 0):

**Delete all the connection strings from your app.config file, and follow the below steps**

1)Right click on your project and add new item
2)Add Entity data model from data section
3)Select Generate from database
4)Click on New Connection
5)Select your existing database from you sql server/ or other you using
6)Than keep doing next and finish

**This will create a new connection string in your app.config file**

**Hope this will solve your prolem**

Comment: I'm trying to utilize code-first methodogy, so I already have all the models built. I simply can't get it to connect to the proper database without it creating its own.